# renovate grouping of python dependencies in single merge doesnt work

Tags: renovate

Im trying to get renovate to group together all python dependency updates under 1 lable and all other updates gives a different label.

my config:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base",
    ":rebaseStalePrs",
    ":semanticCommits"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "groupName": "Python Dependencies",
      "matchLanguages": ["python"],
      "labels": ["data-science-dependencies"]
    },
    {
      "labels": ["renovatebot"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This gives me :

[image]

Any idea why boto3 is not a python? and why its not grouping anything together?

Comment: Are you self-hosting?  If yes, than also paste the bot config. 

Also you probably want to replace the last rule with `"addLabels": ["renovatebot"]` to not replace the labels before.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following configuration:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "prCreation": "immediate",
  "fetchReleaseNotes": "off",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": [
        "pypi"
      ],
      "matchManagers": [
        "pip_requirements"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ],
      "groupName": "Python dependencies",
      "enabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```